# Unable to sign data with X509Certificate in python

Tags: c#, python, encryption, x509certificate, signing

I do not have much experiance with security, but now I have to implement a signature procedure in python.

I have a certificate `somename.cer`. I have an `c#` implementation example of how to sign my string with that string as follows:

CertColl is the collection of certificates where related code finds the related certificate with `Thumbprint` in the previous lines and returns a list of certificates.

```
X509Certificate2 cert = certColl[0]
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
return Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.SignData(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(my_string), new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()));
```

`my_string` is the string to be signed and constructed within the code, but I do not need to add those steps in here

So I am trying to implement this in Python with the help of [this previous Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911373/how-do-i-use-a-x509-certificate-with-pycrypto)

```
from Crypto.Util.asn1 import DerSequence
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from binascii import a2b_base64

pem = open("some-path/somefile.cer")  # I have a certificate with `cer` extension
lines = pem.replace(" ",'').split()
der = a2b_base64(''.join(lines[1:-1]))

cert = DerSequence()
cert.decode(der)
tbsCertificate = DerSequence()
tbsCertificate.decode(cert[0])
subjectPublicKeyInfo = tbsCertificate[6]

rsa_key = RSA.importKey(subjectPublicKeyInfo)
```

As I expect, now I can sign `my_string` with this.

```
rsa_key.sign("Hello World", "")
```

But I receive the following error:

> TypeError: Private key not available in this object

Am I doing something wrong, like usnig the wrong method to mimic `rsa.SignData` in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your certificate does not contain the private key.

From what I see in your C# code, I'm guessing you're sourcing the certificate from the Windows Certificate Store. This store can contain certificates both with and without private key attached.

`.cer` files, on the other hand, (usually) don't contain private keys - they only have public keys. That's why signing with it is impossible.

I'm guessing you have exported the `.cer` file from the Windows Certificate Store and haven't selected the "Export private key" option. You should have better luck by re-exporting it in `.pfx` or `.pvk` format and try signing with that file.

[See more on this topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2292591/1732138)