# what is the difference between .cer & pfx file

Tags: ssl, certificate

People used to say -

cer - certificate stored in the X.509 standard format. This certificate contains information about the certificate's owner... along with public and private keys.

pfx - stands for personal exchange format. It is used to exchange public and private objects in a single file. A pfx file can be created from .cer file. Can also be used to create a Software Publisher Certificate.

** got ref from this link [What is the difference between a cer, pvk, and pfx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292495/what-is-the-difference-between-a-cer-pvk-and-pfx-file) **

but nobody is saying when we should use CERT file and when we should use PFX file. If possible please discuss the situation when we should go for CERT file & when we should go for PFX file. Thanks.

Comment: Also [\[1\]](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/29425/2379), [\[2\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2292495/632951), [\[3\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22788384/632951)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45886431/1599699

Comment: There is algo a good answer here: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29428/177476

Answer (score 147, accepted):

A .pfx includes both the public and private key for the associated certificate (NEVER share this outside your organization); it can be used for TLS/SSL on web site, for digitally signing messages or authorization tokens, or for authenticating to a partner system. A .cer file only has the public key (this is what you typically exchange with integration partners); it can be used to verify tokens or client authentication requests, and it is what is received by an HTTP client from a server in the SSL handshake.

Comment: in case of cert file where private key stored? i saw most of the time people use cert file with wcf...why ? why not they choose pfx file? which one is most secure one?

Comment: u missed one vital point that when people use cert file and when pfx file...it is most important. thanks for answer.

Comment: cert file is a generic term for X.509 Certificate. In the Windows world, the pfx is password protected and should never leave the org. The cer file can be exported from the X.509 certificate as the public key. If you're using X.509 certs from a WCF client for message signing or authentication, you will need to install (or have available in a folder) the pfx file. What did I miss @Thomas?

Comment: plzz answer my second question.

Comment: @Thomas Can you repeat it? Your post has no question marks, so it's hard to tell what's not answered. BTW, a cer file DOES NOT include a private key. ;)

Comment: i asked in what scenario people used pfx file and when go for cert file ?

Comment: another question is that u said private & public key stored in pfx file but only public key stored in cert file. so i like to know where the private key is stored in case of cert file. thanks

Answer (score 21):

2 x scenarios that work slightly differently:

**SCENARIO 1:** 
**Web Browser (Client) accessing Web Page (Server) over HTTPS using SSL.**

The Server has the .PFX File containing both keys. The Client connects to a Website on the Server, and the Server sends a copy of its Public-Key (.CER file) to the Client as part of the SSL handshake. The Client then generates a "SESSION-Key" and encrypts it using the public-key received from the server. The Session-key is then sent back to the server and decrypted to confirm its authenticity. If successfully, both the Client and Server now share the "Session-Key" to communicate using **symmetric** encryption (i.e. both client and server, now both encrypt AND decrypt all messages between each other using the same session-key. All of this is being done behind the scenes in the background of the web browser, between the time of you entering the URL in the address bar, and seeing the web page appear.

**SCENARIO 2:** 
**Application (Client) connects to a FTP Site (Server)** 
or 
**Remote Desktop (Client to Server) using SSH** 
(both examples would apply)

In this scenario, **both** the **Client and Server** will **have their own private and public key pairs** 
*(in contrast to the other examples mentioned in this thread, that only explain when a server has both keys, and the client has the public key only)*

Now, for explanation purposes - Lets label the Key pairs something like:
**A1** and **A2** = as the Servers Private and Public Keys Respectively
**B1** and **B2** = as the Clients Private and Public Keys Respectively

Using this model, previous posts in this thread were talking about when the Server has **A1** and **A2** (*.PFX file*), and shares only a copy of **A2** (*.CER*) with clients

Whereas FTP, or SSH connections (there are other examples out there) consist of **A1**, **A2**, **B1** and **B2** Keys in the entire Client-Server Communication. For instance, 
 - Client connects to FTP Server.
 - Server Sends copy of its public Key (A2) to the Client.
 - Client sends its own public key (B2) back to the Server, completing the handshake.
 - This will now be using **asymmetric** Encryption

Server now has **A1**, (*its own Private*), **A2** (*its own public*), and copy of **B2** (*Client's Public*)
 
Client now has **B1**, (*its own Private*), **B2** (*its own public*), and Copy of **A1** (*Server's Public*)

**Client-To-Server Comms:**
Client uses A2 (servers public key) to encrypt messages bound for the Server,
Server decrpyts them using A1 (Server private key)

**Server-To-client Comms:**
Server uses B2 (clients public key) to encrypt message bound for the Client, 
Client Decrypts them using B1 (Client private key)

***Regarding the .CER and .PFX file Types, the Server ill have its own .PFX that shouldn't be distributed outside your organisation, instead, you should distribute the .CER file out to Clients.***

more info can be found here:
https://www.digicert.com/ssl-cryptography.htm

and here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/107433/why-does-a-ssh-public-key-sit-on-the-server-and-not-with-the-client

Comment: Two typos in this answer: Where you wrote "... , and Copy of A1 (Server's Public) " it should be ", and Copy of A2 (Server's Public)". And in the last paragraph you could change "the Server ill have" to "the Server will have".

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, the question is a bit of apples and oranges, as the cer file is just the public key but the pfx file contains both public and private keys.

So a more fair question would be when would you want to use a pfx file as opposed to a pem file.  Given that pfx files have been criticized for being overly complex, a fair answer to your second question might be: you would only ever want to use a pfx file if you're running IIS and its configuration absolutely won't let you use anything else.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12
(Referenced footnote is an article from Peter Gutmann.)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience (it's not as vast as i want it to be) i use a pfx file when configuring the https binding on an IIS server (since this contains both the public and the private key, you are fine with just that file), a cer file is just the public portion of the key pair (most of the times) and you need to use it in conjunction with a .key file when configuring the ssl  traffic on an nginx or apache server,

As far as i understand there are no more hard reasons to use one or the other,

Answer (score -3):

SSL uses asynchronous encryption, which means that one key (the private key) is given to the server that "owns" the key pair, while the other key (the public key) is distributed freely.
It is called asynchronous because data encrypted with the private key can only be decrypted with the public key, while data encrypted with the public key can only be decrypted with the private key.  So if you want to send something securely to the owner, you encrypt it with his private key and he will be the only one who can decrypt it.  If the owner wants to prove that he sent something, he encrypts it with the private key and anyone who has the public key can decrypt it.  (Once the certificates are installed, this is usually done behind the scenes by the browser or email tool.)
Since the owner wants to keep that private key private, it will be password protected and given ONLY to the owning server (often in a PFX or P12 file).  But the public key will be distributed freely (often in a CER file).

Comment: "you encrypt it with his private key and he will be the only one who can decrypt it." I think you meant, you encrypt it with his public key.

Comment: I think you mean "asymmetric", not "asynchronous".

Comment: You're partly correct - it uses both asymmetric and symmetric encryption. SSL uses asymmetric encryption initially between the client and the server - but only up to the point that the client can verify trust and generate a symmetric key, send that back over to the server (using asymmetric encryption), and then all real data communication happens using symmetric encryption.