# How these .Cer .Pvk .Pfx in makecert / pvk2pfx are related

Tags: x509certificate, signing, pfx

I have gone through this : [What is the difference between a cer, pvk, and pfx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292495/what-is-the-difference-between-a-cer-pvk-and-pfx-file)

I would like to know how these pvk pfx cer are related in between each other?

Comment: Can anyone give some info .. how these are related or whats dependencies in between these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link can be helpful who is running behind this query :sample and provided explanation
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699202.aspx

+
http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/38/using-makecert-to-create-certificates-for-development

One need to create a certificate(.cer) and a private key file(.pvk), and then create  .pfx with these
and this .pfx is using in signing out dll/assembly/file that is going to deploy

Again in short from above URL i mentoned :

.cer - certificate stored in the X.509 standard format.

.pvk - files are used to store private keys for code signing.

.pfx - personal exchange format. for signing

Thanks
Rigin