# ssl certificate differences between pfx .crt intermediate certificates files

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, pfx

I am a little confused about the differences between cert, pfx and intermediate certificates files, could anyone explains them to me.

thanks.

Comment: For file formats/contents, neardupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292495/what-is-the-difference-between-a-cer-pvk-and-pfx-file and cross https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file . For how certs relate and intermediate certs are used, wikipedia is good, every CA has their own similar explanation, and there are many existing Qs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a cer, pvk, and pfx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292495/what-is-the-difference-between-a-cer-pvk-and-pfx-file)

Comment: The answer can fill a book. On Wikipedia lookup: SSL Private Key, SSL Certificate and SSL Certificate Chain. This will help you understand the three types of files from most certificate authorities. Then look up PEM, PFX, PKCS1, PKCS7 and PKCS12 (these are file formats).